# Getting URL parameter using Observables and passing it to the service

Tags: angular, typescript

I'm going to get `id` parameter from URL and pass it to the service and then, get relevant information from API.

The **component** is:

```
export class ShowpostComponent implements OnInit {

  featuredPost: FeaturedPost = {
    id: 0,
    postId: 0,
    subject: '',
    shortDiscription: '',
    discription: '',
    date: '',
    reference: ''
  }

  constructor(
    private FeaturedPostDetail:FeaturedPostService,
    private route:ActivatedRoute
    ) { }

  ngOnInit(): void {
    this.GetPostDetails();
  }
  GetPostDetails(){
    let Id: number;
    this.route.params.subscribe(
      param =>{
        Id = param['id'],
        console.log(Id);
      }
    );
    this.FeaturedPostDetail.GetFeaturedPost(Id).subscribe(
      response =>{
        this.featuredPost = response;
      }
    )
  }
}
```

My problem is that `Id` variable in `this.FeaturedPostDetail.GetFeaturedPost(Id).subscribe` gives error and says:

> let Id: number Variable 'Id' is used before being assigned. ts(2454)

How can I fix it in my code?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The 2 subscriptions are asynchronous, and they start executing at the same time. There is no guarantee that the first one will complete before the other one, but you do have mechanisms at your disposal to make sure they execute in the order you want. For example, you could use [the `switchMap` operator](https://rxjs.dev/api/operators/switchMap) to perform the call to the API as soon as the `id` from your route parameters is available:

```
GetPostDetails() {
  this.route.params
    .pipe(
      map((param) => param["id"]),
      switchMap((id) => this.FeaturedPostDetail.GetFeaturedPost(id))
    )
    .subscribe((response) => {
      this.featuredPost = response;
    });
}
```

Comment: It's not so much the second subscription but the method call using the Id, and your solution shows it very well indeed :)

Comment: I checked your code. There are three errors in your code. 1) its gives error for `map` and says: `Cannot find name 'map'. Did you mean 'Map'?` 2) `param` gives error and says: `Parameter 'param' implicitly has an 'any' type.` 3) `id` gives error and says: `Argument of type 'unknown' is not assignable to parameter of type 'number'`

Comment: You need to import both `map` and `switchMap` in order for this to work. `import { map, switchMap } from 'rxjs';`

Answer (score 0):

All you need to do is give `Id` a default value, such as `-1` or `0` like so:

```
GetPostDetails(){
    let Id: number = -1;
```

Just another note on how the `Id` is set, because `.subscribe` is an observable type that is used to emit values over time, I would highly recommend to refactor `GetPostDetails` into following to make sure the correct value is returned and assigned in time:

```
GetPostDetails() {
    this.route.params.subscribe(
      param =>{
        const Id = param['id'],
        console.log(Id);
        this.FeaturedPostDetail.GetFeaturedPost(Id).subscribe(
        (response) => {
          this.featuredPost = response;
        })
      } 
   ); 
  }
```